# display : block does not working to overwhelm the display : none above?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am newbie with html css and here is my problem

Here is my code

```
https://github.com/anhquanjp/109headerqrcodecss
```

As you can see in my main css,

I wrote the code like this

```
    .header__qr {
    width: 190px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    padding: 8px;
    display: none;
}

.header__navbar-item--has-qr:hover .header_qr {
    display: block;
}
```

My purpose is to hide the qr code and when I hover the mouse to header__navbar-item--has-qr, it will show the qr code by the code display: block.

But it does not show the qr code as I expect.

Could you please give me some advice for this problem ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You didn't use `header__navbar-item--has-qr`  class in your HTML markup

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML in your question rather than in an external site.

Answer (score 0):

In your code there is 2 problem

```
.header__navbar-item--has-qr:hover .header_qr {
    display: block;
}
```

Here you use class name **header__navbar-item--has-qr** but this is not exists in html file. You should use **header__navbar-item--separate** instead of **header__navbar-item--has-qr**

And another on is you declare class name **header_qr**   this name is not also exists in html file. Here you should use **header__qr** instead of **header_qr**.

Replace your code with this one. It should work

```
.header__qr {
    width: 190px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    padding: 8px;
    display: none;
}

.header__navbar-item--separate:hover .header__qr {
    display: block;
}
```